# How can I plot the accuracy as a function of the processing time in Keras?

Tags: performance, plot, time, keras, conv-neural-network

I've been training a CNN in Keras and plotting the training and validation accuracy as a function of epochs. I was wondering if there is a way of plotting the accuracy as a function of processing time.

Reason being that I want to demonstrate the speed of transfer learning as opposed to retraining a full network. When transfer learning is used, the network takes a similar number of epochs to train, give or take, but each epoch takes far less time (an order of magnitude faster) and I want to capture this graphically.

Here is the code I've been using so far:

```
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

print(history.history.keys())
# summarize history for accuracy
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If the number of epochs is constant, what is wrong with simply measuring the entire end-to-end time? it should be a fair comparison for your needs.

Comment: I realize this is trivial, but it is for a presentation and a plot over time looks far better and demonstrates the improvement more clearly than a table of training times does. I have been doing as you have suggested already, but a bit of work for a few visuals goes a long way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's actually really simple to implement a piece of code to perform your task in Keras. In order to do that - it's good to become familiar with a [`keras.callback`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#lambdacallback). It makes possible to call a custom functions on:

`on_epoch_begin`: called at the beginning of every epoch.

`on_epoch_end`: called at the end of every epoch,

`on_batch_begin`: called at the beginning of every batch,

`on_batch_end`: called at the end of every batch,

`on_train_begin`: called at the beginning of model training,

`on_train_end`: called at the end of model training.

So now you might implement e.g. a new callback which will :

- register the start of training time `on_train_begin`,
- at the end of each epoch it will register the actual time of end of computations using `on_epoch_end` in a `dict` provided,
- register the end of training `on_train_end`.

By using the data collected by this callback you could easily present the dependency between time and accuracy in a variety of ways. Of course - it could be easily extended to `batch/iterations` time periods.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a simple concrete example/solution and not just describe what is in the documentation.